# Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to submit this job:

```
sbatch --gres=gpu:v100:1 -p defq -J convolutional-mnist /cm/shared/jobs/convolutional-mnist/convolutional-mnist.slurm
```

sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available

But the configuration seems to be right. Here's the sinfo output:

```
$ sinfo -o "%.10P %.5a %.10l %.6D %.6t %.20N %.10G"
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE             NODELIST       GRES
 defq*    up   infinite      1   idle             cnode001 gpu:v100:1
 defq*    up   infinite      2   idle       cnode[002-003]     (null)
  idle    up   infinite      1   idle             cnode001 gpu:v100:1
  idle    up   infinite      2   idle       cnode[002-003]     (null)
  long    up   infinite      1   idle             cnode001 gpu:v100:1
  long    up   infinite      2   idle       cnode[002-003]     (null)
```

Please note that node cnode001 belongs to the defq and has the gres string gpu:v100:1.

I don't understand why Slurm is saying Requested node configuration is not available.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe due to default number of CPUs, or memory, or timelimit... :-?

Answer (score 0):

What's in the submit script `/cm/shared/jobs/convolutional-mnist/convolutional-mnist.slurm`? Could it be, as Poshi suggested, this script sets up a conflicting set of parameters to the `defq` partition? Does it work if you omit `-p defq`?